# Boolean Value Not Being Changed in If Statement

Tags: java, android

I have two classes: GameScreen.java and KeyButton.java. There are three buttons that are boolean values (of whether or not they are pressed) referenced in the GameScreen class that I want to compare to values in the KeyButton class. Here is the relevant code:

GameScreen.java:

```
private void checkButtons() {
// Log.d("GameScreen","Note and Bar Intersected");

KeyButton keybutton = new KeyButton();

  if (B1Pressed == keybutton.getB1() && B2Pressed == keybutton.getB2() && B3Pressed == keybutton.getB3()) {
     // Log.i("GameScreenTest", "Correct");
      score++;
  } else {
     // Log.i("GameScreenTest - Result", "Wrong");
     // Log.i("GameScreenTest - Button Pressed", Boolean.toString(B1Pressed));
     // Log.i("GameScreenTest - Button Required", Boolean.toString(keybutton.getB1()));
  }
}
```

KeyButton.java:

```
public class KeyButton {

public boolean B1 = false;
public boolean B2 = false;
public boolean B3 = false;

Rectangles Rectangles = new Rectangles();
{

    //C major
    if (ScalesScreen.scaleType.equals("C")) {
    //C
    if (GameScreen.intersected == Rectangles.rectangle1) {
            B1 = false;
            B2 = false;
            B3 = false;
        }
    //D
    if (GameScreen.intersected == Rectangles.rectangle2) {
            B1 = true;
            B2 = false;
            B3 = true;
        }
    //E
    if (GameScreen.intersected == Rectangles.rectangle3) {
            B1 = true;
            B2 = true;
            B3 = false;
        }
    //F
    if (GameScreen.intersected == Rectangles.rectangle4) {
            B1 = true;
            B2 = false;
            B3 = false;
        }
...
public boolean getB1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Log.d("Key 1", Boolean.toString(B1));
    return B1;
}

public boolean getB2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Log.d("Key 2", Boolean.toString(B2));
    return B2;
}

public boolean getB3() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Log.d("Key 3", Boolean.toString(B3));
    return B3;
}
```

For some reason, the B1, B2, and B3 values are returning false in the GameScreen code (from keybutton.getB1()) causing the score to increase whenever the buttons aren't pressed. So, for some reason, the Boolean values aren't being changed to what they are supposed to be in the KeyButton class. What can I do to fix this?

ADDED:

```
 for (Rect rect : rectangles) {

   if(Rect.intersects(rect, bar)) {
     //  Log.d("GameScreen", "intersected");
    intersected = rect;
    //  Log.d("Intersected", intersected.toString());
    checkButtons();

  }
}
```

Comment: Are the four intersection checks accidentally nested inside the `if (ScalesScreen.scaleType.equals("C"))` block?

Comment: Should the boolean values change if all buttons are pressed or if any one of the button is pressed

Comment: @Shashank Udupa They should change depending on if the intersected rectangle (added part of code) is the same as Rectangles that are defined in a different class (called Rectangles, which don't change).

Comment: your code in `keyButton.java` appears to have statements outside of a method (i.e. the `if` statements aren't contained in a method...) - I'm surprised your aren't getting compiler errors.  Or is there more code that you are leaving out?  It's hard to tell when you are calling the code that sets B1, B2, B3 to the values that you expect.

Comment: @rothloup The only code I'm leaving out in `KeyButton.java` is where the `...` is and that is because there are numerous rectangles I am checking against. The code, otherwise, is as you see above.

Comment: @rothloup I believe what he has is an instance initializer block, so all that code is actually getting copied into his constructor/s by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks dave now I understand.

Comment: @user2712795 check out Sree solution below, I believe it is essentially the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new KeyButton Object whenever CheckButton Method gets called. Which is the case in which the flags will be reseted each time.

```
KeyButton keybutton = new KeyButton();
```

Instead of that use a global instance of Keybutton or Make **KeyButton** as single instance. So that flags will persist.

```
public class KeyButton
{
    public boolean B1 = false;
    public boolean B2 = false;
    public boolean B3 = false;

    // Singleton
    private static KeyButton sInstance;
    private KeyButton () {}

    public static synchronized KeyButton getInstance()
    {
        if (sInstance == null)
        {
            sInstance = new KeyButton();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    ..
}
```

Comment: I added this to my code and changed my code to `KeyButton keybutton = KeyButton.getInstance();` but all the boolean values are still returning false.